# How to change titleTextAttributes of UIBarButtonItem after it's pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a navigation bar with several UIBarButtons that I initially display with an alpha of 0.5, and would like to display with an alpha of 1 after pressed. I am storing these attributes in normalAttributes and highlightedAttributes.

I set up the buttons in the following manner:

```
colorButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Colors", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showColors))
colorButton.setTitleTextAttributes(normalAttributes, for: .normal)
colorButton.setTitleTextAttributes(highlightedAttributes, for: .selected)
```

This leads to the button briefly switching to the highlightedAttributes, which is expected. However, within the button's action showColors I then perform the following:

```
textButton.setTitleTextAttributes(highlightedAttributes, for:[])
```

I have also tried using .normal instead of []. Neither method seems to have any sort of effect on the button. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are `colorButton` and `textButton` the same object? Are you forgetting to assign textButton to `colorButton`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this I can think of is using a custom view. Meaning, create a separate `UIButton` and make a reference to it in your class (e.g., `let yourButton = UIButton()`). Initialize your bar button item with `UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourButton)` and then use it however you want to.

Just note that you'll need to add your `action`/`target` pair on `yourButton`, not on the bar button item. Then in your `action` handler, `showColors` in your case, you can change the appearance of `yourButton`.

You can either toggle `alpha` directly or if it's just text we're talking about, you could do:
`yourButton.setTitleColor(yourColor, for: .normal)`
and 
`yourButton.setTitleColor(yourColorHalfAlpha, for: .selected)`.

Then in your `showColors`, just call `yourButton.isSelected = !yourButton.isSelected` to toggle the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIButton` contains a `UILabel` as the `titleLabel` property. Just set its attributes the usual way instead of setting them via the button’s pass-through functions.